# Maximise magnetic force at one point while minimizing at another

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, metals

Is it possible to have a magnet that attracts one object strongly, but not another object behind that first object?

Given an (electro-) magnet M above two thin parallel steel sheets P1 and P2 in the following configuration:

```
      M          (magnet)
----------- P1   (steel sheet)
----------- P2   (steel sheet)
```

Is there a configuration that would maximize the attractive force between M and P1 while minimizing the attractive force between M and P2?

I.e. a magnet that would grip P1 very strongly, but not P2?

I know that generally the strength is proportional to the square root of the distance, but is there a particular configuration of multiple magnetic poles such as a Halbach array, that would change this?

Can the gradient of the magnetic force, or the strength with which it permeates the first steel sheet be manipulated this way?

Or is the force working on these objects simply a function of the overall strength of the magnet and the distances involved?

Comment: A soft iron watch case helps protect the mechanism from magnetic fields. I hope this helps.